# Impulse train: why an indeterminate result?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I have an impulse train given by

$$\frac{1}{R+1}+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^R \cos(\frac{2k \pi x}{R+1})}{R+1}$$

It seems obvious to me that, for $x=0$, the function returns $1$. This is because $\cos (0)=1$, and we therefore end up with $\frac{1}{R+1}+\frac{R}{R+1}=\frac{R+1}{R+1}=1$.

However, my math software (Mathematica) gives an indeterminate result at $x=0$. Usually this means there is a division by $0$ somewhere. But I can't see any reason for this function to produce an indeterminate result. (This is about the *maths* of the situation, not the way the software works.)

Can anyone explain?

Comment: It is indeed the case that, when $x = 0$, the expression evaluates to $1$ (assuming that $R \neq -1$). With that being said, the only real question is why your software did what it did.

Comment: You're right about the math; I'm not sure why Mathematica would stumble here. Maybe it's nervous about $R$? I would try setting R to be some specific value and checking what it says then.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll go over to the software site and ask there. (Assigning a value to $R$ makes no difference, BTW.)

Comment: SymPy has a similar problem. Defining just the sum, then substituting $x = 0$ yields an unevaluated sum $\sum_{k = 1}^R 1$, which is very strange! I'm a little disappointed in both CAS's.

Comment: Could you show the result obtained for $\sum_{k=1}^R \cos(\frac{2k \pi x}{R+1})$ ? Whatever it could be, could you try a Taylor expansion of it around $x=0$. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Claude. The result for $\sum_{k=1}^R \cos(\frac{2k \pi x}{R+1})$ is indeterminate for $x={0,3,6,9...}$. I assume this is to do with the conversion to $csc$ form, as you suggest below. What I can't figure out is whether this means that the original expression actually *is* indeterminate depending on how it's re-expressed, or whether I can think of it a a glitch and work happily with the original expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the problem in Wolfram Development Platform and the limit is properly given.

The only thing I noticed is that the simplification of the result is not as good as it could be since, using another CAS,
$$\sum_{k=1}^R \cos \left(\frac{2 k\pi   x}{R+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi  (2 R+1) x}{R+1}\right) \csc \left(\frac{\pi
    x}{R+1}\right)-1\right)$$ making

$$\frac{1}{R+1}+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^R \cos(\frac{2k \pi x}{R+1})}{R+1}=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  (2 R+1) x}{R+1}\right) \csc \left(\frac{\pi 
   x}{R+1}\right)+1}{2 (R+1)}$$ Probably, the indetermination comes from the limit of $\csc(t)$ when $t\to 0$ while, using Taylor expansion 
$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi  (2 R+1) x}{R+1}\right)=\frac{( \pi (2 R+1) ) }{R+1}x-\frac{( \pi  (2R+1) )^3 }{6
   (R+1)^3}x^3+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$\csc \left(\frac{\pi  x}{R+1}\right)=\frac{R+1}{\pi  x}+\frac{\pi  x}{6 (R+1)}+\frac{7 \pi ^3 x^3}{360
   (R+1)^3}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi  (2 R+1) x}{R+1}\right)\,\csc \left(\frac{\pi  x}{R+1}\right)=(2 R+1)-\frac{2 \pi ^2 R (2 R+1) }{3 (R+1)}x^2+O\left(x^4\right)$$